# Which discrete math book would you recommend?

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

I am deciding whether to buy Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and its Applications or Knuth's Concrete Mathematics. Can you guys tell me the pros and cons of each? Thank you.

Comment: I have no experience with Rosen's, but I did quite enjoy Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik.  In particular I like how it gave several problem sets at the end of each chapter at highly varying levels of difficulty from easy homework to test level to still open problems and potential research topics with conveniently located solutions in the back (or partial solutions or hints for the research level questions).  As a first introduction to the subject, it may be a bit difficult, but as a second time visiting I found it just right.

Answer (score 1):

To me, a very good one would be:

**Invitation to Discrete Mathematics, (J. Matousek, J. Nesetril)**

Answer (score 0):

Grimaldi is also a good book on discrete maths